# Can a class in a module use the attributes of the class that extends the module?

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance, module, extends

An example might be:

```
module SharedStuff
  def has_foo
    !@foo.nil?
  end

  class StuffGenerator
    def initialize
      # super can't work here
    end

    # Will return nil.
    def try_foo
      @foo
    end
  end 
end


class NeedsSharedStuff < BaseSource
  include SharedStuff
  def initialize
    super
  end
end

class AlsoSharedStuff < OtherSource
  include SharedStuff
  def initialize
    super
  end
end

class BaseSource
  attr_reader :foo, :bar
  def initalize
    @foo, @bar = get_foo, get_bar
  end
end

class OtherSource < BaseSource
  def initialize
    super
  end

  def extra_stuff
    # whatever...
  end
end
```

I've lost my `@foo` and `@bar` attributes in the nested classes within `SharedStuff`. Is there a way to get it without resorting to this?:

```
module SharedStuff
  def has_foo
    @foo.empty?
  end

  def stuff_generator
    StuffGenerator.new @foo, @bar
  end

  class StuffGenerator
    attr_reader :foo, :bar
    def initialize(foo, bar)
      @foo, @bar = foo, bar
    end

    def try_foo
      @foo
    end
  end 
end
```

I know this isn't right because I still can't reach `has_foo` in the parent module.
I'm sort of new to using mixins and modules in Ruby, is there a way to arrange this to get the methods in `SharedStuff` and the instance methods of the classes that extend it inside of the `StuffGenerator`?

Answer (score 0):

You can still inherit inside of modules. All I needed was the `@foo` and `@bar` attributes, so I just went to the `BaseSource` and got them. `:D`.

```
module SharedStuff
  def has_foo
    !@foo.nil?
  end

  class StuffGenerator < BaseSource
    def initialize
      super
    end

    # Will return foo.
    def try_foo
      @foo
    end
  end 
end
```